# How to load another component inside a onChange function in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this following  code

```
var SelectOption = React.createClass({

  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      data: []
    };
  },

  handleemployeeChange: function() {
        alert('sssss');

  },

  loadOptionfromServer: function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: this.props.url,
      dataType: 'json',
      cache: false,
      success: function(data) {
        this.setState({
          data: data
        });
        console.log(data);
      }.bind(this),
      error: function(xhr, status, err) {
        console.error(this.props.url, status, err.toString());
      }.bind(this)
    });
  },

  componentDidMount: function() {
    alert('sssss');
    this.loadOptionfromServer();
    //setInterval(this.loadCommentsFromServer, this.props.pollInterval);
  },


  render: function() {
    return ( < SelectOptionList data = {
        this.state.data
      }
      />
    );

  }
});

var SelectOptionList = React.createClass({

  render: function() {
    var commentNodes = this.props.data.map(function(list) {
      return ( < Addcontenttoselect id = {
          list.emp_ide_id
        }
        option = {
          list.emp_name
        } >
        < /Addcontenttoselect>
      );
    });
    return ( < select id = "select1"
      className = "form-control"
      data - placeholder = "Basic Select2 Box"
      onChange = {
        this.handleemployeeChange
      } > {
        commentNodes
      } < /select>
    );
  }
});

var Addcontenttoselect = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return ( < option value = "{this.props.id}" > {
      this.props.option
    } < /option>);
  }
});

ReactDOM.render( < div className = "col-md-3" > < h3 > Select Employee to Review < /h3><SelectOption  url="/appraisal / employeelist " pollInterval={70000}  /></div>, document.getElementById('select-box'));
```

So this component creates a Select Tag in the browser , I want to take the Value of the selected option and Call another component which will create a Table from a data got from API

Any leads please let me know

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

With react you have multiple ways to pass around data to your components, it depends heavily on the use and the complexity of your application.

If you have a lot of components which need to know about the state/data of another component you should look at application architectures like flux or redux. [Facebooks Flux](https://facebook.github.io/flux/docs/overview.html)

For some applications a full data flow architecture can be overkill so it depends on how you design your components. A common pattern is to have one component who handles the state/interactivity of your application.
Your main component will hold all the business logic of your app and pass down functions to its child to e.g. change state.
You can read more about this here [Facebook thinking react](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/thinking-in-react.html)

I did a little fiddle which adresses your challenge:

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t4av5woy/3/)

```
var Select = React.createClass({
render: function() {
var selectOptions = this.props.options.map(function(optionData) {
    return (
    <option key={optionData.id} value={optionData.id}>
        {optionData.name} 
    </option>
  );
});

return (
    <select 
    id="select1"
    className="form-control" 
    placeholder="Basic Select2 Box"
    onChange={this.props.onChange}
    > 
     { selectOptions } 
    </select>
   );
 }
});


  var SelectApp = React.createClass({
  // The main component holds the data
  getInitialState: function() {
  return {
    data: [],
    currentData: null
  }
},

componentDidMount: function () {
  this.loadOptions();
},

loadOptions: function () {
  var _this = this;
  return setTimeout(function() {
    _this.setState({data: [
    {
        id: 1,
      name: 'Foo Bar'
    },
    {
        id: 2,
      name: 'Bar Foo'
    }
  ]});
  }, 2000);
},

onChange: function (e) {
  var employeeId = e.target.value,
    _this = this,
    mockedData = [
    {
        id: 1,
      data: 'Good employee'
    },
    {
        id: 2,
      data: 'Not so good employee'
    }
  ];

// Mocking an additional data fetch
setTimeout(function () {
    var result = mockedData.find(function (employeeData) {
    return (employeeData.id == employeeId);
  });

  _this.setState({
    currentData: result
  });
}, 2000);

},

renderResult: function () {
if (this.state.currentData) {
    return (
    <div>
                <h4>Employee:</h4>
      <p>{this.state.currentData.data}</p>
    </div>
  );
}

return;
},

render: function() {
return (
  <div>
    <div>
      <h3> Select Employee to Review </h3>
      <Select url={this.props.url} options={this.state.data} onChange={this.onChange}/>
    </div>
            {this.renderResult()}
  </div>
 );
}
});

ReactDOM.render(<SelectApp url="/appraisal / employeelist " pollInterval={70000} />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

Edit:

```
renderResult: function () {
if (this.state.currentData) {
    return (
     <loadUserAppraisal url="something" empid={this.state.currentData.id} />
  );
}
```

Comment: I have a component called `<loadUserAppraisal url="something"  empid="IMP132" >` I wanted to render this component when I select one of the ID's from the dropdown list . So can you tell me where to tweek in the code to do that ?.

Comment: I thin probably inside that OnChange function ??

Comment: edited my answer, the on change would not work because it is not included in the final render. you could perform the fetch of data in the on Change function and then set state with the new values. After that the renderResult function will take care. if you do it this way you don't need to pass the url and id as props, instead the fetched data.

Comment: Okay I am going to try to implement this :) thank you for explaining this to me , I am getting a bit hang of Unidirectional Data Flow architecture .

Comment: I tried to do the way you said but the other component never loads 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37209087/how-to-pass-data-from-a-child-component-to-parent-component-in-reactjs